# subtract from symbols in ruby

Tags: ruby, symbols, subtraction

I would like to find the first valid image among a list in ruby. Here is my code:

```
 if(params[:id])

   @image = Image.find_by_id(params[:id])
   while @image.nil?
    :id-- ?
    @image = Image.find_by_id(params[:id])
   end
```

In that block, how can i keep decreasing the id # until a valid image is found? :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't subtract from a symbol. A symbol is not a number.

What you seem to want to do is to decrease the value of `params[:id]`, which is of course perfectly possible (after converting the id from string to integer) by doing `params[:id] = params[:id].to_i - 1` or

```
id = params[:id].to_i
while @image.nil?
  @image = Image.find_by_id(id)
  id -= 1
end
```

The latter is better than the first because it does not mutate `params` (which there is no good reason to do).

However you should NOT do either of those, because you can achieve this with *much* less hassle, by letting the db do the work:

```
Image.find(:first, :order => "id DESC", :conditions => ["id <= ?", params[:id]])
```

PS: Ruby doesn't have a `--` operator, so you have to use `-= 1` to decrement a number.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using find_by_id(id), not find_by_id(params[:id])? Otherwise @image will be the same all the time, as you're not decrementing the value inside params.

Comment: No worries, and +1 to your answer!

Comment: Thank you... Hmm. By the first method, I am getting :undefined method `-' for "1653":String" 1653 is the id I am using here. By the second method, which accesses the DB, I am seeing "Couldn't find Image without an ID" Don't know what to make of it...

Comment: @matea: Oh, yes, of course. `params[:id]` will contain a string. You'll need to convert it to integer to subtract from it. Either way you should use the last solution in my answer, everything else is pointless.

Comment: Oh perhaps for the first method, I need to somehow turn id into an integer?

Comment: Thank sepp2k, yes your last solution is by far the neatest. What do you make of "Couldn't find Image without an ID"?

Comment: The trace is showing this... "vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:1509:in `find_from_ids'
vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:590:in `find'
app/controllers/images_controller.rb:31:in `newest'"

Comment: @matea: It's what you get when you forget the `:first` option, like I originally did. You get that error because without `:first` or `:all`, `find` expects the ID of the searched object as its first argument.

Comment: The bigger win using the query to find the image is that you won't have to repeatedly hit the database if your request was a miss. The database will dutifully find the first that matches the request and return a result. It's a great example of using the database for what it's best at - retrieving exactly the data needed.

Comment: In Rails 3 you'd write that as `Image.where('id <= ?', params[:id]).order('id DESC').first`.